# JointJS - handle links (join, delete)

Tags: javascript, jointjs

[image]

When connecting the ports two ports, I want to get the ID of port1, and ID of port2. For instance, I connect Yes from left side, to No on other side, and I want to get ID of Yes Port, and ID of No Port. So far I have tried this:

```
this.graph.on('add', function(cell, collection, opt) {
 if (cell.isLink()) {
    console.log(cell.id);
 }
});
```

How ever, I only get the ID of first line (not port) I clicked on. I would also like to get the same output upon removing the line.

```
    this.graph.on('remove', function(cell, collection, opt) {
        if (cell.isLink()) {
            alert('link removed;');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using graph's "add" event won't help you because if the link is draggable, when you add it you'll only have the source id and port but not the target's id and port.

The events "change:source" and "change:target" won't be called when you remove a link either and they also have the disadvantage of being called several times when dragging the link around.

I'd suggest you use the paper "link:connect" event and graph's "remove" event as follows:

```
this.paper.on("link:connect", function(linkView, evt, cellView, magnet, arrowhead) {
    logSourceTargetPorts(linkView.model);
}

this.graph.on("remove", function(cell, collection, opt) {
    if (cell.isLink()) {
        logSourceTargetPorts(cell);
    }
}

function logSourceTargetPorts(link) {
    var source = link.get('source'); 
    var target = link.get('target');
    if(source.port && target.port) {
        console.log("source and target ports: ", source.port, target.port);
    }
}
```

There's also the paper "link:disconnect" event that has the same signature as "link:connect" in case you also want to do something when the link is disconnected, not only removed.

Answer (score 0):

In JointJS ports in an element don't have id. They have port names (and maybe port groups) what you can do is to find the id of the source and target element on the link that you're removing. Then get the ports that your link was connecting them.
Here is an example: [Linking between elements](http://resources.jointjs.com/tutorials/joint/tutorials/ports.html#link)

```
graph.on('change:source change:target', function(link) {
var sourcePort = link.get('source').port;
var sourceId = link.get('source').id;
var targetPort = link.get('target').port;
var targetId = link.get('target').id;

var m = [
    'The port <b>' + sourcePort,
    '</b> of element with ID <b>' + sourceId,
    '</b> is connected to port <b>' + targetPort,
    '</b> of elemnt with ID <b>' + targetId + '</b>'
].join('');

out(m);
});

function out(m) {
    $('#paper-link-out').html(m);
}
```